# Multiple JSON objects inside a JSON object instead of in an array

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

I am using an API that gives the following response. (I have reduced the amount of objects inside Data to 2 for simplicity).

```
{
"Response": "Success",
"Message": "Coin list succesfully returned!",
"BaseImageUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
"BaseLinkUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
"Data": {
          "42": {
          "Id": "4321",
          "Url": "/coins/42/overview",
          "ImageUrl": "/media/19984/42.png",
          "Name": "42",
          "CoinName": "42 Coin",
          "FullName": "42 Coin (42)",
          "Algorithm": "Scrypt",
          "ProofType": "PoW",
          "FullyPremined": "0",
          "TotalCoinSupply": "42",
          "PreMinedValue": "N/A",
          "TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
          "SortOrder": "34"
          },
          "365": {
          "Id": "33639",
          "Url": "/coins/365/overview",
          "ImageUrl": "/media/352070/365.png",
          "Name": "365",
          "CoinName": "365Coin",
          "FullName": "365Coin (365)",
          "Algorithm": "X11",
          "ProofType": "PoW/PoS",
          "FullyPremined": "0",
          "TotalCoinSupply": "2300000000",
          "PreMinedValue": "N/A",
          "TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
          "SortOrder": "916"
          }
},
"Type": 100
}
```

I want to put all of the objects inside Data in an array so that I can pass them to my RecyclerView's adapter.

I make use of Retrofit2 and RxJava2 for my network operations.

This is the code of my retrofit builder at the moment:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

I also generated the POJO classes Coin and Data using: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

I have edited the class Data so that it contains an array of Coin instead of a single object:

```
public class Data {
@SerializedName("Coin")
    @Expose
    private Coin[] coins;

    public Coin[] getCoin() {
        return coins;
    }

    public void setCoins(Coin[] coins){}
}
```

How would I go about adding all the objects inside Data to the Coin array?
Do I need to create a custom converter and if yes how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your Data class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


@JsonAdapter(Data.DataJsonAdapter.class)
public class Data {
    private Coin[] coins;

    public Coin[] getCoin() {
        return coins;
    }

    public void setCoins(Coin[] coins) {
         this.coins = coins;
    }

    public static class DataJsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Data> {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Data value) throws IOException {
            // TODO: Maybe implement
        }

        @Override
        public Data read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            ArrayList<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<>();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.nextName(); // Read "42", "365", ...
                coins.add(gson.fromJson(reader, Coin.class));
            }
            reader.endObject();

            Data data = new Data();
            // Can probably be simplified
            Coin[] array = new Coin[coins.size()];
            coins.toArray(array); // fill the array
            data.setCoins(array);

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in you code, just call:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(yourJson, Data.class);
```

I haven't but you should probably check that there is a next of the expected type when you read the reader, to prevent crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class All_Plan  {

    @SerializedName("Coin")
    private ArrayList<CoinData> data;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    public ArrayList<CoinData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<CoinData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this solve the problem of getting all of the objects inside Data in an array?